# What's the *actual* meaning behind the I²C reserved addresses?

Tags: i2c, standard, addressing

I'm building a `i2c-tiny-usb` compatible adapter, and am trying to implement a "transparent side channel" for advanced configuration/features of the adapter.

My idea was to "abuse" some of the reserved addresses, by having the adapter firmware detect and "redirect" (by calling an internal function, instead of forwarding the data to the I²C port) those.

Looking through the [official spec](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf), the following addresses are reserved:

```
HI   LO  R¯W
0000 000  0  general call ("broadcast address")
0000 000  1  START byte
0000 001     CBUS compatibility       *
0000 010     different bus format     *
0000 011     future purposes
0000 1       Hs-mode                  *
1111 1    1  device ID
1111 0       10bit address
```

(asterisks next to the addresses I'm talking about below)

my hardware supports 10bit addressing, and up to 1Mbaud "Fast Mode Plus", and the only thing (apart from a literal bus company) I could find about CBUS was some australian home automation product and a vague description of an ancient standard using some "I²Cish plus another clock/direction pin" combination i won't even have the pins for.

My question(s) now would be:

- Given there's little info on CBUS and whatever "different bus format" is even supposed to mean, except that "devices that don't support it have to ignore it", does anyone know more about what those 2 compatibility formats mean?
- Would I be safe to "hijack" them and/or the Hs-mode to get essentially up to 6 (2 addrs + 2 bits in Hs) "virtual I²C devices" without impacting the functionality being "100% spec compatible with any up-to-Fm+ I²C device", if my adapter doesn't actually ever try to put those addresses on the bus?

Comment: Holy, this last paragraph is one hell of a sentence... :D

Comment: @jusaca yeah i'mma reformat that a bit :P EDIT: better? don't know how to phrase it shorter without losing info.

Comment: You could always add a second usb endpoint as a side channel. Something like a serial port perhaps?

Comment: @Bryan yes i could, but if i was able to reuse a few of those without any compatibility impact (like the 4 High-Speed Master codes, given my master just doesn't do high speed) it would simplify usage because now you just talk to another I2C address through the same device handle, instead of a whole different USB device driver or character device or such. note `i2c-tiny-usb` is a kernel module, providing the adapter to the kernel's driver subsystem, not just some library.

Comment: @glen_geek i'm not *claiming* anything, i'm trying to *make* it compatible. one is a legal statement / advertisement, the other is a technical goal. please specify what you mean by "you might" though, are you giving me permission (thanks but i knew i'm allowed :D), telling me it *will* work (if so, what addrs specifically with which caveats?), or just chatting? :P

Comment: I should modify my comment (to be deleted): although your *bus transactions* might be I2C-compatible, your software driver abuses I2C specs, since it re-purposes addresses. No doubt, your re-purposing might work OK for *you*, but your hijacking only weakens trustworthiness of I2C communications for everyone else.

Comment: @glen_geek apart from device drivers / host software mistakenly believing my hacks over the actual spec, is there anything that can actually go wrong there though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s nothing wrong with your approach as long as you document it and allow changing the side-channel address.

Suppose you default to address *a* for the side channel. If someone really needs to use that channel, they can use send a message to that address to have it change to address *b*. The latter would not be used in their particular application/system.

IMHO that would be nice.

Another approach is that of using a special address *and* a special format. Eg. a message with a 64-bit or longer hash chopped up into bytes and moved to locations in the message that are determined in a way that accommodates all message lengths.

For example, there’s the original side-channel message, and you compute an 8-byte-long hash of it. Then start going down a list of 8 prime numbers longer than the longest side-channel message possible. For each prime, take it modulo the message length, and stick the hash number into that position in the message. Move the original byte that was there to the end of the message. Repeat for all hash bytes. Collisions with legitimate user message on a rarely used (since reserved) I2C address are practically excluded.

For people who don’t believe in probabilities, leave the option of sending a (hashed) command that will nevertheless change the reserved address in use.

Comment: yeah that sounds good, the hash is a bit overkill, i think i'll just go the "readressable" way and then default to an "illegal" address to keep out of the way, while allowing the user to push a button to switch to a "legal" default on powerup in case their OS is "too smart" and filters the addresses.

and about "document it", yeah i think i'mma actually write some docs for `i2c-tiny-usb` while working on this anyway, because somehow they never existed :P

Comment: yeah i think i figured out an "everyone pleasing" option: i have a button, an RGB led and some eeprom to work with in addition to the usb+i2c ports, so i'll just say on powerup push the button and the led shows the address, with `R=0x07` (Hs mode controller code 3), `G=0x70` (to stay with the trend), `B=register` (settable via the current address, default `0x700` just in case you need a default 10bit addr). then a few seconds after you last pushed the button (or if you didn't at all, or if the register was written), it'll store the settings in eeprom, and expose button+led via i2c.

Comment: aaaand i just realized `0x700` is 11 bits so nevermind that, gonna pick another nice looking number, maybe `0x380` to stay with the other trend (3 `1`s in a row at an end)?